# How to change the duration of a Layer in Blender?

Tags: layers

How to change how long a layer is visible, for example for making blinking eyes or having a character disappear

Comment: Hello, what kind of layer are you talking about, could you please give more details?

Comment: Kinda like any layer just sorta change how long it is visible for.

Comment: What do you *mean* by "layer"? There are *Render Layers* in the compositor, there are *Bone Layers* for armatures, and there are even *data layers*. [Blender 2.79 has layers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/layers.html), in Blender 2.8 they are called now *Collections*. So which layer do you mean now? Which Blender version do you use? Please be a little more specific...

Comment: I am a blender beginner only started using it last week and I am using blender version  3.6.5  and I am talking about the  layers like the default cube that is there when you startup blender and its listed under collection.

Comment: I think they are called Object layers or data blocks because when I copy and paste it says paste data blocks from internal clipboard.

Comment: You can animate the visibility of the object in the Outliner, put your cursor on the camera icon and press i, then move in the Timeline, disable the option and press i again, is it what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the cube invisible from frame 20, put your timeline cursor at frame 19, put your mouse cursor over the camera icon in the *Outliner* and press <kbd>i</kbd>:

[image]

At frame 20 disable the icon and press <kbd>i</kbd>:

[image]

If you want to hide in viewport as well, the option *Disable in Viewport* is available here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works. But is there a way to view it without rendering it?

Comment: Yes, do the same but this time with the eye icon

Comment: It says hide_veiwport can not be animated.

Comment: Yes sorry you need to display the Disable in Viewport icon, see my edit

Comment: Thank you so much.